# Sending a registration request to Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to send a post request to my Laravel app so that I could create a `User` without the UI.

I've tried sending a post request via cURL:

`curl --data "name=test&password=password120918&email=app@test.com" http://localhost:8080/register`

This didn't work.

This is a fresh install of Laravel 5.4

I can't find anything to do with the `RegisterController` in the `routes/web.php` file.

What would the url to register a user be for Laravel 5.4? (I'm pretty sure it works the same way as 5.3)

Thank you.

Comment: In your `routes/web.php` is there a *post* catch for `/register` like `Route::post('/register', RegisterController@yourfunction)` or create resource controllers https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Nope, no `/register` at all.. @linktoahref

Comment: Perhaps you want to run `php artisan make:auth` Read more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that in laravel there is a default way to do things, But if your just looking to create a user from post request and send it back as a response you can do it yourself.

in your routes.php

```
Route::post("/users", "UsersController@store");
```

Then create a UsersController.php and add the method:

```
public function store(Request $request){

   //You should add validation before creating the user.

   $user = App\User::create([
      "email"  => $request->email,
      "name"   => $request->name,
      "password" => bcrypt($request->password)
   ]);

   if(!$user){
      return response(["error" => "Your error here"], 400);
   }

   return response(["user" => $user], 200);

}
```

Then try it our with postman or curl command like

```
curl -X POST -F 'name=Testing User' -F 'password=pass1234' -F 'email=testing@gmail.com' http://localhost:8080/users
```

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan route:list
```

Will show you all of the registered routes for your application. When using Laravel's built in auth, routes are registered without them actually being in your routes file.

By default Laravel adds a `POST` route for `/register` to

```
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register
```